# SQL Command To Delete Entry In Current Textfields For Java App

Tags: java, sql, tomcat, jdbc

I have a Java program where I connect to a database running Tomcat. The app includes fields for First Name, last name, email, phone. I created a button when clicked allows you to add the entries in the text fields to the database.

Below I have shown the structure of adding an entry. I use the same method for removing a client entry. The problem is the SQL command. I am not sure how to write it.

Question: I need a SQL command where (like adding a client) I can have any data from the database loaded in the fields and take that info and delete that specific entry in the database. Please help.

Insert Client (in Queries class):

```
//create INSERT that adds a new entry into the database
            insertNewPerson = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO Addresses " + 
                    "(FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber ) " +
                    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" );
```

Method to add person (in Queries class):

```
//ADD an entry
    public int addPerson(
            String fname, String lname, String email, String num)
    {
        int result = 0;

        //set parameters, then execute insertNewPerson
        try {
            insertNewPerson.setString(1, fname);
            insertNewPerson.setString(2, lname);
            insertNewPerson.setString(3, email);
            insertNewPerson.setString(4, num);

            //insert the new entry; return # of rows updated
            result = insertNewPerson.executeUpdate();
        }//end try
        catch(SQLException sqlException) {
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
            close();
        }//end catch

        return result;
    }//end method addPerson
```

Action Performed (in application class and with GUI):

```
//handles call when insertButton is clicked
            private void insertButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                int result = personQueries.addPerson(firstNameTextField.getText(), lastNameTextField.getText(), emailTextField.getText(), phoneTextField.getText());

                if (result == 1)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Person added!", "Person added", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Person not added!", "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


                browseButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }//end method insertButtonActionPerformed
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
DELETE FROM
    Addresses
WHERE
    FirstName = <Your value here> AND
    LastName = <Your value here> AND
    Email = <Your value here> AND
    PhoneNumber = <Your value here>
```

This will delete from `Addresses` where all conditions are true.

A more elegant solution would probably be one where you delete a row with a primary key.

Comment: If one of these fields is set as a unique primary key, you could send only that unique primary field in your where clause to save on the amount of data being passed around.

Comment: Just added that before I saw your comment. :)

Comment: But you see how I set the values to the SQL command in the addPerson method. I need to do the same but delete this time.

Comment: Just do like you do with `insert`: `deletePerson.setString(1, fname);`

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. It says there is an error in SQL command.