# Sql Command To Delete Values Taken From Text Fields

Tags: java, sql, tomcat, jdbc

I use this command to insert a new client, I have a method in Java where I assign the values to the command:

```
insertNewPerson = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO Addresses " + 
                    "(FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber, ClientAddress ) " +
                    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" );
```

Question: I am looking for something similar but for DELETING whatever entries are in the text fields of the program.

Here is the Java method I use to set the values in the sql command:

```
public int addPerson(
            String fname, String lname, String email, String num, String caddress)
    {
        int result = 0;

        //set parameters, then execute insertNewPerson
        try {
            insertNewPerson.setString(1, fname);
            insertNewPerson.setString(2, lname);
            insertNewPerson.setString(3, email);
            insertNewPerson.setString(4, num);
            insertNewPerson.setString(5, caddress);

            //insert the new entry; return # of rows updated
            result = insertNewPerson.executeUpdate();
        }//end try
        catch(SQLException sqlException) {
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
            close();
        }//end catch

        return result;
    }//end method addPerson
```

Comment: you want to delete database entries or modify the SQL?

Comment: "DELETING whatever entries are in the text fields of the program" Uh, what?

Comment: So I have five text fields (FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone and Address). My program can insert and delete whatever you type into those fields into a database. The above method is how I insert entries but I cannot use the same method or Sql command to delete entries. Note my program can find clients by typing last name. eg. I  find a client and his info pops up in the text fields. If I press "remove Client" it does not work. I need a way to gather whatever in in the textfields and assign it to the sql command as I did for adding a client.

Comment: If you have any User_ID field then pass it to your delete query!

Comment: How is this different from your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551413/sql-command-to-delete-entry-in-current-textfields-for-java-app ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are looking for the `DELETE` SQL Command:

```
delete from Addresses 
where FirstName = ?
and LastName = ?
and Email = ?
and PhoneNumber = ?
and ClientAddress = ?
```

This also takes into consideration your need to delete based on the values on the fields.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a unique value for all records. If you have a primary key you can use this block.

```
deletePerson = connection.prepareStatement(
    "DELETE FROM Addresses " + 
    "WHERE personID = ?" );
```